# How to split a file into multiple files based on a delimiter, and remove the delimiter also, in Unix

Tags: shell, unix

I have a file that somewhat looks like this:

```
{1:F195}{2:O5350646}{3:{1028:076}}{4:
:16R:GL
:16R:ADD
:19A::P//U9,1
:16S:AFO
-}{5:{MAC:00}{CHK:1C}}{S:{SAC:}{COP:S}{MAN:P2}}${1:33339}{2:O53}{4:
:16S:G
:16R:A
:19A::H0,
:19A::H0,
:16S:ADDINFO
-}{5:{MAC:0}{CHK:4}}{S:{SAC:}{COP:S}{MAN:GP2}}
```

Now I want to split this single file into two files based on the delimiter `$` and then remove the delimiter also. Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

I have used the following logic:

1. First at every occurrence of `$` go to a new line.
2. I'm able to create multiple files but those are having delimiters.

Code:

```
FILE=test.dat
sed 's/\$/\n&/g' $FILE > Inter_$FILE 
FILE=Inter_$FILE

cat $FILE | while read line
do
            sleep 1
            FormattedDate=`date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S`
            Final_FILE=New_${FormattedDate}_$FILE

            echo "line --- $line"
            echo "FormattedDate --- $FormattedDate"
            Line_Check=`echo $line | tr '$' '@' |  cut -c1`
            ##Line_Check=`sed -e 's/\$/@/g' $line |  cut -c1`
            echo "Line_Check --- $Line_Check"
            echo "Final_FILE --- $Final_FILE"

            if [ "$Line_Check" = "@" ]
            then
                           Final_FILE=New_$FormattedDate_$FILE
                           FILE=$Final_FILE

                           echo "FOUND In  --- $line"
                           echo "FILE  --->>>  $FILE"

            else
                           FILE=$Final_FILE
                           echo "FILE  --->>>  $FILE"
                           ###`echo $line |  cut -c2-` >>
                           ###cat $line` >> $FILE
                           ###Filter_Line=`echo $line`
                           ###echo "Filter_Line  --- $Filter_Line"
            fi

            echo $line >> $FILE

            ###sed 's/^@//' $FILE > 3_$FILE

done

sed 's/^\$//' $FILE >> Final_$FILE;
```

Comment: i tried the baove logic but the problem is im not able to remove those delimeters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you may be trying to reinvent the wheel. `awk` is a great tool that can be used to split files on delimiters and perform other text processing. You may like to try the following:

```
awk '{ for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) print $i > "file_" i ".txt" }' RS= FS='\\$' file
```

Results:

Contents of `file_1.txt`:

```
{1:F195}{2:O5350646}{3:{1028:076}}{4:
:16R:GL
:16R:ADD
:19A::P//U9,1
:16S:AFO
-}{5:{MAC:00}{CHK:1C}}{S:{SAC:}{COP:S}{MAN:P2}}
```

Contents of `file_2.txt`:

```
{1:33339}{2:O53}{4:
:16S:G
:16R:A
:19A::H0,
:19A::H0,
:16S:ADDINFO
-}{5:{MAC:0}{CHK:4}}{S:{SAC:}{COP:S}{MAN:GP2}}
```

---

Explanation:

Set the Record Separator to null, which puts `awk` in 'paragraph mode' (by default `RS` is set to `"\n"`, which enables line-by-line processing). Since your file doesn't look like it contains paragraphs, this will essentially treat your file as a single record. We then set the Field Separator to a dollar-sign character (which needs to be escaped). So for each record (and there should only be one record) we loop over each field (`NF` is short for Number of Fields) and print it to a file using the iterator. It's worthwhile noting that you will get strange results if your input contains multiple paragraphs. In comparison with Glenn's answer above/below, his solution won't have this problem, but the last file it processes will contain a trailing newline. HTH.

Comment: Thanks a lot steve for your answer. Worked like a charm. I'm pretty new to shell scripting can you tell exactly what the awk code is doing.?

Comment: @user2647888: I've added a brief explanation for you. Please let me know if more detail is required. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Use awk, it has a dedicated "input record separator" variable

```
awk -v RS='$' '{ outfile = "output_file_" NR; print > outfile}' filename
```

This program prints each line into a separate file with the line number as a suffix ("output_file_1", "output_file_2").